# React Navigation 6: Override parent navigator's header configuration from an screen inside child navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have a `BottomTab` navigator nested inside an `Stsck` navigator. And the header is configured via Stack `screenOptions`:

```js
function AppStackNavigator() {
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={getScreenOptions}>
        <Stack.Screen name="BottomTab" component={BottomTabNavigator}/>
        ...
      </Stack.Navigator>
  )

  const getScreenOptions = ({route, navigation}) => {
    // crazy logic ... 
    return {
      headerLeft: getHeaderLeft,
      headerRight: getHeaderRight,
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

And in the `BottomTaB` navigator I have an screen called `Target`.  Notice that the `headerShown` is set to `false` here.

```js
function BottomTabNavigators() {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
          tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props}/>}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Target" component={TargetScreen}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

In target screen I am overriding the `headerRight` of the **PARENT** navigator, because I need direct interaction between header and a method (`methodThatIsOnlyAccessableHere`) which is only accessible inside this screen:

```js
function TargetScreen() {

  const  methodThatIsOnlyAccessableHere = () => { ... }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const getHeaderRight = () => {
    // call methodThatIsOnlyAccessableHere
    ...
    }

    const parentNavigator = navigation.getParent()
    parentNavigator.setOptions({
      headerRight: getHeaderRight,
    })

  }, [navigation])
}
```

### Current behaviour:

The top level header configuration (`screenOptions` in Stack navigator) is working perfectly. When navigating to `Target` screen, the overrided header configuration (using `setOptions` ) will become active. **However**, when leaving  this screen, this overrided configuration still remains active (Undesired behaviour)

### Desired behaviour

When leaving `Target` screen, the top level header  configuration should become active and the overrided configuration should become effectless.

### Why is this my design choice ?

I am always hiding the nested navigator header (the header of the `BottomTab` navigator) and configuring the top level (parent) navigator header (`Stack` navigator) based on the state of the child navigator. I cannot move the header configuration  of `Target`  screen to the parent because in this case I will not have access to `methodThatIsOnlyAccessableHere`.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to update `headerRight` again. For instance: use the cleanup of your `useLayoutEffect` hook.

```js
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const getHeaderRight = () => {
    // call methodThatIsOnlyAccessableHere
    ...
    }

    const parentNavigator = navigation.getParent()
    parentNavigator.setOptions({
      headerRight: getHeaderRight,
    })

    // cleanup
    return () => {
      parentNavigator.setOptions({
        headerRight: null
      })
    }

  }, [navigation])
```

Comment: When leaving the Target screen, this clean-up will make the overridden configuration effectless (which is correct), **however**,  the  the top-level header configuration will not  get active again (this is **incorrect**). I already mentioned this in the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your TargetScreen function runs for each route call, to override the parent element whenever possible.
If true, you could reset the options at the start of your useLayoutEffect hook, and, again assuming your getParent() call checks for which kind of page youre accessing, it would reset the current page navigation whenever the effect gets called whithout affecting its overriding call.